# Add specific characters to zend router

Tags: zend-framework, routes

Is here any way to use space or "!" in zend url? 
There code i have for routing :

```
'route'    => '/city[/:action][/:id]',
 'constraints' => array(
 'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
 'id'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
  ),
```

Now i can have this type of urls : /city/index/Paris , but if i put this - /city/index/New York, it doesnt work giving me a 404 error. 
I have tried to put into 'id' this -

```
 '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-][ ]*'
```

or

```
 '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-][%20]*'
```

, but again 404.

EDIT

And if i add to constraints cyrillic characters, like this

```
'id'     => '[a-zA-Zа-яА-я][a-zA-Zа-яА-Я0-9_-]*',
```

i cannot use url like /city/index/Москва.
Please help me.

Comment: Just add a single white space in your regex pattern. Use this '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_- ]*' pattern for you id match in route.

Comment: No, it doesnt work. Even city/index/Paris stopped working with this. Gives 404

Comment: A URL must not contain a literal space. It must either be encoded using the percent-encoding or a different encoding that uses URL-safe characters.

Comment: Got it, thanks Unex. So, i should remove all spaces, before adding a sity to database. And what about cities with cyrillic? Can i use such urls, or need to translate that?